# What is the hidden "GDI+ Hook Window" in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gdi+

Whenever any C# application opens its first form that contains a control within a process, a hidden window named **"G"** is opened, whose class name is **"GDI+ Hook Window Class"**, as shown by the application below:

[image: Window List]

Here is the code used:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public class Form1 : Form {
        private delegate bool EnumThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        private EnumThreadDelegate showWindowName;
        private Button button1;
        private string windowList = string.Empty;
        private Button button2;
        private int increment;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, EnumThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = false)]
        private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        public Form1() {
            showWindowName = ShowWindowName;
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        }

        [STAThread]
        public static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
            base.OnShown(e);
            button1_Click(null, null);
        }

        private bool ShowWindowName(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam) {
            increment++;
            StringBuilder windowName = new StringBuilder(65535);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, windowName, 65535);
            StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder(65535);
            GetClassName(hWnd, className, 65535);
            windowList += "Window " + increment + ":\n\tTitle: " + windowName + "\n\tClass Name: " + className + "\n\n";
            Invalidate(false);
            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(windowList, Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            increment = 0;
            windowList = string.Empty;
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, showWindowName, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                EnumThreadWindows(thread.Id, (hwnd, lParam) => {
                    StringBuilder windowName = new StringBuilder(65535);
                    GetWindowText(hwnd, windowName, 65535);
                    if (windowName.ToString() == "G")
                        SendMessage(hwnd, 0x10, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                    return false;
                }, IntPtr.Zero);
            button1_Click(null, null);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent() {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 379);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Reload";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(429, 0);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 379);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Kill G Window";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 402);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
}
```

If I close that window programmatically (by clicking the **"Kill G Window"** button), the window closes but the program's form keeps running as expected, seemingly completely unaffected.

What is the purpose and function of this mysterious window?

Comment: Could it be a WinSpy++ thingie?

Comment: No, `EnumWindows()` lists it even without WinSpy. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Rather than showing screenshot, can you show the code and produced output? I am [curious](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/why-gdi-window-visible.1983509/) and lazy at the same time.

Comment: I don't want to use WinSpy++. You said *"EnumWindows() lists it even without WinSpy"*.

Comment: To check - you're aware of what [IME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418266(v=vs.85).aspx) usually stands for in Windows? If so, have you installed one and tried out interacting with the form before/after you force close the window?

Comment: I can reproduce "Gefault IME" but I think it's an artifact of WinSpy++ mangling something, with Microsoft's Spy++ the caption for the same window is "Default IME" which is much less mysterious.

Comment: Ok, apparently the GDI+ window is not actually captioned "Default IME", meaning that it actually does not have anything to do with IME. It is simply captioned "G" as shown in the question.

Comment: It is plumbing for gdiplus.dll, it provides synchronization for background threads used by GDI+.  The docs for GdiplusStartup() talk about them, exactly what they do is unclear.  Since System.Drawing relies on gdiplus.dll to get the job done, you'll always see this window back in a Winforms app.  You need to ignore it.